# how to display the value of getElementById().value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display on the screen the value of `getElementById().value` . So I have a form and I fill the input than when press a button I want to display the value of what the user has written to input box//
I am trying to do this like below:

```
<label id="l1"><script>document.writeln(document.getElementById('lastname').value)</script></label>
```

but nothing happen when I press the button
What can I do? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to `document.open()` first.  [Read the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20001113/html.html#ID-35318390).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.writeln. Instead use a DOM method like `.innerHTML` to set the value of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it out of the label into a javascript function, try also using a span or a div instead of a label with an id.

Answer (score 0):

try
 script>document.writeln(document.getElementById('lastname').getAttribute('value')

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(){
var get_value_button=document.getElementById('get_value')

get_value_button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var lastname_val = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    document.getElementById('l1').innerHTML=lastname_val;
    return false;
}, true);

});
```

jsFiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dVu4/3/)

1. You should do it after document loaded see first line of code.
2. You should get element and bind 'click' event handler. Second and third line.
3. Inside 'click' event handler you should get value. Forth line.
4. And then get your label element and write your obtained value to it using innerHTML.